# How to set the valid time for a password reset link generated with asp indentiy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

For our new project we want to leverage as much of the asp.net mvc 5 as we can. This includes making use of the AspNet.Identity toolset for our user administration.

We are using the following version(s):

```
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" 
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46"
```

In our previous roll-your-own applications we made sure that reset links can be used only once, and that they expire within a day or so.

Does does AspNet.Identiy support something similar? I could not find it in the documentation.

To pass our security checks the link should at least expire.

How to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity by default generates reset tokens based on existing user properties. This means that when those properties change, the reset token is automatically invalidated. This will meet your one time use requirement (when they use the token and reset their password, the token will no longer be valid).

Reset token expiration can be set when you assign an `IUserTokenProvider` to the  `UserTokenProvider` property of your `UserManager`.

A good example of `IUserTokenProvider` is `DataProtectorTokenProvider` found in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` package. This class uses the previously mentioned security stamp based tokens and allows for expiration times to be set using the `TokenLifespan` property. For info on how to implement this [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549124/3274800).

Comment: The one-time use is confirmed. +1 for that. I could add a my own "SendTokenTime" to the User class and check it when the try to use the link. However if it's true what Shyamal posts, tokens are valid for one day, I would introduce a conflicting valid method...

Comment: Yeah, I can't count the amount of times I've seen/used the token lifespan, don't know why I didn't remember it earlier... I'll update my answer on how to set it up in a bit.

Comment: Answer updated. Let me know if you need any help with `UserManager`.

Answer (score 6):

to control the lifetime of the token, go to **IdentityConfig.cs**, next, and the end of the **Create** function, within the last if related to **dataProtectionProvider** you can set the time, look:

```
 if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
                        dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")){
                        **TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)**
                    };
            }
```

Use the **TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) (or the time that you need)**

Comment: Avellanda: Are we taking about the same versions? In my solution there is no IdentiyConfig.cs

Answer (score 3):

By default the token is valid for one day. However, you can change that by customizing the Create method in App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs file

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
   manager.UserTokenProvider =
   new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
      (dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
      {                    
         TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
      };
}
```

With the code above, the forgotten password and the email confirmation tokens will expire in 3 hours.

Do make sure that your application has a way for users to regenerate token. I had added a Resend Link button. It links to the function that regenerates the token and sends link to the user.

You will more details here: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: Are we taking about the same versions? In my solution there is no IdentiyConfig.cs

Comment: Check out this link. You need to update your Visual Studio Version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599528/identityconfig-cs-is-missing-in-my-c-sharp-web-application-project/32065811#32065811

Comment: That post deals with stuff in VS2013 I'm using 2015 with versions metioned in my question. Those do not have the IdentiyConfig. A full solution search on "TokenLifeSpan" yielded no resutls

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio 2015 but by default if you create an MVC template all these classes are included in the VS2013 Version 4+. Please try creating an MVC template and see if you get all these classes. If not let me  know I would send you a MVC template created from VS2013 Version 5 and then you can copy those classes to your project.

Comment: I use the MVC version included in VS 2015 straight out of the box, and it doesn't have those config files.

Comment: Try MVC template and not Emtpy MVC project